# .htaccess redirect to subfolder (If domain name is base domain name)

Tags: .htaccess

```
domain => subdomain.domain.com
target => subdomain.domain.com/Controller/Method
```

I will

```
IF %{HTTP_HOST} == base_url(subdomain.domain.com)
```

redirect to target *(subdomain.domain.com/Controller/Method)*

I have not fix base domain name

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# Considering that base domain URL excludes index.html, index.php, welcome.html or something like that, we'll reduce matches to http(s)://base.subdomain/ and http(s)://base.subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?$
RewriteRule /Controller/Method
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

##IF host==subdomain.domain.com##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sudomain\.domain\.com$
##And uri==/##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
##redirect to http://subdomain.domain.com/Contreller/method##
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.domain.com/Controller/method [NC,L,R]
```